# Как правильно реализовывать привязку данных wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, классы, binding

Сейчас я не особо разбираюсь в привязке. Точнее совсем не разбираюсь.
Итак, вот моя проблема:
Сразу оговорюсь : **Я прекрасно понимаю, что на данном этапе у меня каша как в этом случае, так и в голове. Если у вас есть источники, в которых данная тема более-менее понятно описана, напишите об этом пожалуйста.**

У меня есть форма, которая выводит информацию об ингредиенте. У этой формы есть два ListView: для разновидностей и товаров.

Все данные берутся из SQL базы.
К каждому ингредиенту привязан набор разновидностей и товаров.

Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Товаров в БД пока нет.

Ошибка заключается в том, что записи дублируются три раза в ListView разновидностей.

Класс для отображения я прописывала в классе этой формы (что, скорее всего не правильно).
Вот его код:

```
public class Raznovidnosti : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string kod, nazv;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string Kod
    {
        get { return kod; }
        set { kod = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Kod"); }
    }

    public string Nazv
    {
        get { return nazv; }
        set { nazv = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Nazv"); }
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы ввести данные в этот класс я делаю цикл foreach в соответствующей таблице, который вернула результат запроса.

```
    SqlCommand s5 = new SqlCommand(@"Select Kod, Nazv from Raznovidnosti_ingr where Kod_ingr = " + Util.Get_kod_i(), con);
    SqlDataAdapter da5 = new SqlDataAdapter(s5);
    da5.Fill(raznt);//table запись в таблицу

    foreach (DataRow ro in raznt.Rows)
    {
        Raznovidnosti r = new Raznovidnosti();
        r.Kod = ro[0].ToString(); r.Nazv = ro[1].ToString();
        razn_cl.Add(r);// razn_cl переменная имеет тип данных List<Raznovidnosti>
    }
    DataContext = razn_cl;
```

Далее, привязка, о правильности которой даже и мыслей нет:

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="Raz" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nazv}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Здесь ещё должна быть реализация обновления при добавлении ( добавляется через новое окно ). В базу через запрос, естественно, всё добавляется.

Какие есть пути решения? Возможна ли привязка не к классу, а к полю таблицы, например.

**Я прекрасно понимаю, что на данном этапе у меня каша как в этом случае, так и в голове. Если у вас есть источники, в которых данная тема более-менее понятно описана, напишите об этом пожалуйста.**

Comment: Привязка ту не при чем. Ставьте точку останова на строке `DataContext = razn_cl; ` и смотрите, что вы в свой список пишете и сколько раз вы это делаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот самый простой способ. Вы в коде при Sql запросе добавляете данные в razn_cl, но не очищаете. Достаточно при вызове в начале их очищать. Плюс, вам возможно могут придти данные с повторениями. Тут либо править sql запрос, либо убирать дубли на стороне вашего приложения. Если в приложении, то просто вызов Distinct после цикла, если в Sql, то Distinct в запросе. Вот как можно сделать

```
razn_cl.Clear();
SqlCommand s5 = new SqlCommand(@"Select Kod, Nazv from Raznovidnosti_ingr where Kod_ingr = " + Util.Get_kod_i(), con);
SqlDataAdapter da5 = new SqlDataAdapter(s5);
da5.Fill(raznt);//table запись в таблицу

foreach (DataRow ro in raznt.Rows)
{
    Raznovidnosti r = new Raznovidnosti();
    r.Kod = ro[0].ToString(); r.Nazv = ro[1].ToString();
    razn_cl.Add(r);// razn_cl переменная имеет тип данных List<Raznovidnosti>
}
razn_cl.Distinct();
DataContext = razn_cl;
```